# What happens if i rotated a DC motor's rotor?

Tags: current, dc, dc-motor, sine, rotor

a 3V DC motor. If i rotated its rotor at a constant RPM without any DC input, what will the output current be at the terminals?

will it be a constant Sine wave or DC?

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if i have access to an oscilloscope and a motor

Comment: there are many people on the internet who would not have considered that an option for either safety or knowledge reasons so I'm sorry I gave you a suggestion that you had already considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a simple permanent magnet DC motor:

More or less DC, but with pulses (gaps between the commutator sections) and noise (varying resistance between the brushes and the commutator.)

Comment: depending on how many poles the motor has.

Comment: @JRE The motor must have a permanent magnet. The question says "without any DC input".

Comment: Yes, it is a DC motor with a permanent magnet

Comment: The question doesn't specify the motor type beyond "3VDC" motor.  Given the basic level of the question, I assume a simple permanent magnet motor of the type normally found in toys.  A BLDC motor or a motor without a permanent magnet would be different, of course.

Comment: BrushedDC?  (DC with a few blips), BLDC? (AC fundamental and specific shape depends on whether l-l or l-n)

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate a brushed DC motor at constant speed, it will create a voltage at the terminals.  This voltage is often called a back-emf.  Most DC motor datasheets will give you the back-emf constant (Ke) which is usually given with the units of V/kRPM or V/(rad/sec).  This constant tells you the DC voltage created at the lead wires of the motor for a given speed.  (Note that a lot of hobby/RC motors give you the inverse of the back-emf constant, which they call Kv.)

You will not get a true DC voltage from the motor.  A DC armature is made up of a number of different coils connected to the commutator.  Each of these coils actually produces an triangular AC back-emf waveform but the commutator and brushes act as a rectifier to give you DC with a slight ripple.  The ripple will depend on the resistance and inductance of the winding, as well as the number of commutator bars.